# not able to insert record in table in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database, ipad

I made iPad application in which,

I want to insert record into database table, but I am unable to do the same.

here is my code snippet,

```
-(void) insertRecordIntoTableNamed: (NSString *) symbol{

NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO recentquotes ('symbol', 'dt_tm') VALUES ('%@',datetime())",symbol];

   NSLog(@"sql=%@",sql);

    char *err;                          

    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Error updating table.");
    }

}
```

my NSLog shows:

```
sql=INSERT INTO recentquotes ('symbol', 'dt_tm') VALUES ('PATNI',datetime())
```

this statement is correct, but i am unable to see VALUES `PATNI` and `datetime()` in my database table

here is rest of the code,

```
NSString *filePahs = Nil;
-(NSString *) filePath {

    filePahs=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"companymaster" ofType:@"sql"];
    NSLog(@"path=%@",filePahs);
    return filePahs;
}
```

result of above method is:

path=/Users/krunal/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/9FF61238-2D1D-4CB7-8E24-9AC7CE9415BC/iStock kotak.app/companymaster.sql

```
-(void) openDB {
    //---create database---

    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Database failed to open.");
    }
}



-(void) getAllRowsFromTableNamed: (NSString *) tableName {
    //---retrieve rows---
    NSString *qsql = @"SELECT * FROM recentquotes";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) ==
        SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"b4 while");
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
                NSString *field1Str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: field1]; 

            [recentqotarray addObject:field1Str];
            [field1Str release];

        }
        //---deletes the compiled statement from memory---
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        NSLog(@"recentqotarray=%@",recentqotarray);
    }   
}
```

### edit

i wrote this, and when i checked my log i got like this, "in find data" , i didn't got my sql=...

```
     - (void) finddata
{
    NSString *databasePath;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    NSLog(@"in finddata");
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM recentquotes"];
        NSLog(@"sql=%@",querySQL);
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {                
                NSLog(@"Inside recent quote table");
                char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
                NSLog(@"Column name=%s",field1);
                NSString *field1Str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: field1]; 


                [recentqotarray addObject:field1Str];
                NSLog(@"array=%@",recentqotarray);

              } 
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
}
```

***Thanks In Advance***

Comment: What happens when `symbol = @"Krunal's"`?

Comment: symbol (PATNI) is correct, because when i copy query of NSLog and paste inside sqlite, record gets inserted into database, but it doesn't work through code

Comment: I was just pointing out a SQL injection vulnerability in your code that you should be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO recentquotes ('symbol', 'dt_tm') VALUES ('%@',datetime())",symbol];
```

Instead of `'%@'` try using `\"%@\"` , and check if it inserts into your db.

EDIT:

I've been working on DB a lot lately, and i've been able to successfully insert data in my sqlite, i'll write down what i use check if it helps:

```
NSArray*dirPath;
NSString*docDir;


dirPath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docDir=[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath=[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"example.sqlite"];


BOOL success;

NSFileManager*fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
success=[fm fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

if(success)
{
   NSLog(@"Already present");
}

NSString*bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSError*error;
success=[fm copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:databasePath error:&error];

if(success)
{
    NSLog(@"Created successfully");
}
const char*dbPath=[databasePath UTF8String];

if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &myDB)==SQLITE_OK)
{

        NSString*insertSQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into extable (name) values (\"%@\")",[nametextField.text]];

        const char*insertStmt=[insertSQL UTF8String];
        char *errmsg=nil;

        if(sqlite3_exec(myDB, insertStmt, NULL, NULL, &errmsg)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"ADDED!");
        }

 sqlite3_close(myDB);
}
```

Comment: still unable to insert record

Comment: check the edit, that's how i've been inserting data, try if its of any use.

Comment: If there is a button action which will save your data, should be in that button action.

Comment: there is no button action, can i write this inside method , and call that method in did load ?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. Try breakpoints to check is the "ADDED: is logged.

Comment: i tried this, i got SIGABRT error, and my log shows "Already present"

Comment: That means there is already a database in your documents directory, can you put breakpoints inside `if(sqlite3_open)` and check where exactly it gets that SIGABRT.

Comment: i also got "EXE_BAD_ACCESS" at this line, if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, db)==SQLITE_OK)

Comment: i hope your path is loggin properly and it should be `&db` not just `db`, i hope there is a `sqlite3*db` in your .h file

Comment: it should be `&db` too is it crashing even after the change?

Comment: me getting warning in that line,incompatible pointer type passing 'sqlite3' on db

Comment: Yes it shows that warning when you put `if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, db)==SQLITE_OK)` instead of `if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db)==SQLITE_OK)`, note that `&` before db

Comment: ohh great, i wrote &db instead db, i got NSLog as, "ALREADY PRESENT","ADDED"

Comment: Great! then i guess it is added.

Comment: BUT still i am unable to see in my sqlite

Comment: how are you checking your contents ? you should go to `library->application support->iphone simulator->4.3/5.0 (whatever the simulator you using)->applications->there should be folders of your applications choose the one you are trying out-> there in documents folder you'll have the updated sqlite`

Comment: ohhh yes, i was checking wrongly that's get inserted successfully.. thanx dude, it helps me a lot :-)

Comment: i want to retrieve all this record in my array can i retrieve this ?

Comment: yes i can, but it'll look horrible as a comment. I'll write it when i get some free time. Just wanted to make sure you could insert in your DB, for now just go through this tutorial http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/, if you couldn't get the retrive part. Just comment here, i'll get back home and write it up

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application, this is much better i feel.

Comment: i tried techotopia.com's example but i am not getting success.. plz help me dude

Comment: did you follow the find contact method in that example?

Comment: So where and what problem is occuring ? In your case.

Comment: Ya i looked at it, so what/where is the problem ?

Comment: i am not getting anything in this statement                              NSLog(@"sql=%@",querySQL);

Comment: @krunal: Try to check the error. Try adding an `else` part as follows: `if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &db) == SQLITE_OK){...}else{NSLog(@"Error=%s",sqlite3_errmsg(&db));}`. Btw what is the type of `db`? Is it `sqlite3` or `sqlite3*`?

Comment: I'm guessing `if(sqlite3_open)` is failing, put a break point inside the loop and check if it goes in. If it doesn't you have to copy and paste from `NSArray*dirPath;` to `if(success)` from my edit. Because databasePath was retrieved inside another method. So you've to retrieve databasepath properly again.

Comment: @another i tried else part i got like this,  Error=unable to open database file